# Как исправить это?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я хотел сделать программу которая должна читать RGB код из .txt файла , и выводить это на экран с помощью sc.fill(()).

Но выходит ошибка invalid color argument!

прога разделена на 2 части.

Вот 1 часть:

```
import pygame

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((526,526))
clr = open("clr.txt", "w+")
run = True

while run:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if ev.key == pygame.K_b:
                clr = open("clr.txt", "w+")
                clr.write("0,0,255")
            if ev.key == pygame.K_w:
                clr = open("clr.txt", "w+")
                clr.write("255,255,255")

    sc.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

1 часть исправна , но вторая...

```
import pygame

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((526,526))

run = True

while run:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    clr = open("clr.txt", "r")
    sc.fill((clr))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Код 2 части почему то говорит что: **Цветовой Аргумент Не Верный.**

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: sc.fill((clr)) - clr - это  цвет, а вы отдаете ему file handler. прочитайте цвет из файла вгначале

Comment: то-есть попытаться разбить его на 3 переменных (числовых) а потом уже в сделать вот так: sc.fill((clr1,clr2,clr3))?

Comment: именно так. Правда, я не знаю структуры файла, но логика правильная

Comment: структура такая: 255,255,255 (RGB код)

Comment: да, тогда split и int

Comment: спасибо огромное!